# Replace token to different token only when the token is inside some specific tag

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

```
const lessonText = "<div><blockquote>&quot;&quot;</blockquote><p>Heni &quot;</p><blockquote>no quotation</blockquote><span>hi</span><blockquote><span style=\"font-family:Courier New,Courier,monospace;\">row.names(vol) &lt;- c(&quot;</span></blockquote></div>"
```

Regex to capture and replace `&quot;` with `"` when `&quot` is inside `blockquote` tag, that means i don't want `&quot` here, `<p>Heni &quot;</p>`, to be changed to `"`.

[image]

Comment: and why do you need regex instead of fixing the source HTML directly?

Comment: Including in nested tags?

Comment: the source is coming from CKEditor editor(WYSIWYG),  from backend. So no way to modify HTML directly.

Comment: question updated

Comment: @wiktor why it's not a regex question?

Comment: See [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3832970).

Comment: It's a string, I've added a screenshoot in the question. And I would like to replace some tokens before displaying it in html using regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm thinking it's a regex question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need a proper HTML parser to support nested tags, for example, `blockquote` tags could be nested.

Here is a solution if you can live with the limitation of not supporting corner cases. It uses nested replaces, the outer one to identify `blockquote` tags with its content, the inner one to take action on the `blockquote` content:

```js
const lessonText = "<div><blockquote>&quot;&quot;</blockquote><p>Heni &quot;</p><blockquote>no quotation</blockquote><span>hi</span><blockquote><span style=\"font-family:Courier New,Courier,monospace;\">row.names(vol) &lt;- c(&quot;</span></blockquote></div>"
let result = lessonText.replace(/(<blockquote>)(.*?)(<\/blockquote>)/g, function(m, g1, g2, g3) {
  return g1 + g2.replace(/&quot;/g, '"') + g3;
});
console.log('Result: ' + result);
```

`Result: <div><blockquote>""</blockquote><p>Heni &quot;</p><blockquote>no quotation</blockquote><span>hi</span><blockquote><span style="font-family:Courier New,Courier,monospace;">row.names(vol) &lt;- c("</span></blockquote></div>`

Explanation of outer replace regex:

- `(<blockquote>)` -- capture group 1: opening `blockquote` tag
- `(.*?)` -- capture group 2: non-greedy scan over content until:
- `(<\/blockquote>)` -- capture group 3: closing `blockquote` tag
- `/g` flag -- replace all patterns

Note:

- Limitation: This fails with nested tags
- If you expect attributes for the `blockquote` you could use regex `(<blockquote( [^>]*)?>)` instead (which does not support corner cases like `<blockquote tile="<gotcha>!">`)
- If you expect newlines in the `blockquote` content you can use regex `([\s\S]*?)` instead.

Explanation of inner replace regex:

- `&quot;` -- capture literal `&quot;` text (you could use string `"&quote"` instead)
- `/g` flag -- replace all patterns

Answer (score -2):

You can try :

```
lines = lines.replace(<blockquote.*?<\/blockquote/g, (fullMatch, g1) => {
    return fullMatch.replace(/&quot;/, '"');
});
```